# Jetpack Compose: AndroidView Color in Dark Theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I found the colors of `AndroidView` in my app do not change with dark theme setting. For instance, I have a textView, whose textColor remains black(or grey) when system is in dark theme, causing the content hard to recognize. Of course I can set color for the textView like:

```kotlin
val textColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.White.toArgb() else Color.Black.toArgb()
...

    TextView(context).apply {
    ...
        setTextColor(textColor)
    ...
}
```

It works fine, but the question is that I get such textView in a few different screens, and I do not wish to repeat the same stuff like above in each of them. I've considered using `CompositionLocal`, but in that way I have to expose something like a `LocalTextColor` outside of the Composable functions to be imported by Composable functions in other packages and can't call `isSystemInDarkTheme()` to know how to set the correct value of it.
Is there any better idea to solve this question than simply repeating the same code everywhere? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify colors in your theme and retrieve the colors from there. This approach makes it possible to easily support dark theme and nested themes. You can retrieve the `Colors` provided to the `MaterialTheme` composable by using `MaterialTheme.colors`.

```
    private val Yellow200 = Color(0xffffeb46)
private val Blue200 = Color(0xff91a4fc)
// ...

private val DarkColors = darkColors(
    primary = Yellow200,
    secondary = Blue200,
    // ...
)
private val LightColors = lightColors(
    primary = Yellow500,
    primaryVariant = Yellow400,
    secondary = Blue700,
    // ...
)

MaterialTheme(
    colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors
) {
    // app content
}
```

and in composable:

```
Text(
    text = "Hello theming",
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
)
```

Comment: Can't believe I forget this... Thank you!

Comment: If it was helpful, please vote up